# plt.plot() cause blue screen on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, matplotlib, bsod

This code cause a blue screen on windows on my computer :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10),range(10)) # This is the line that cause the crash
```

WhoCrashed tells me this :

> This was probably caused by the following module: nt_wrong_symbols.sys
> (nt_wrong_symbols) Bugcheck code: 0x124 (0x0, 0xFFFFB60A6AF4D028,
> 0xB2000000, 0x70005) Error: WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR

Here is a link to the full [Minidump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lhC9ij1D8XEaPiD01niU9f1ovX8TnW-q/view?usp=sharing)

What I have done:

- Fully tested the CPU with a CPU-Z stress test
- Fully tested the RAM with memtest86+
- Tested the GPU with Assassin's creed origin in full ultra
- Tested the same code on Ubuntu (double boot) : works fine

This lead me to believe this is a windows specific error.

Hardware configuration :

- i9-7940X
- GTX 1080 Ti
- 64 Gb RAM @2400Mhz (CPU frequency)

Software :

- Windows 10, fresh install (I've always had this issue)
- Python 2.7 installed through Anaconda ( I tested the code with Jupyter and IPython with the same results)
- Windows and graphic drivers up to date

This is the only thing that causes blue screen on my computer, and I'm out of ideas on how to solve this, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE : I asked this question here as it appears to be matplotlib related, I hope this is the right place

EDIT : Correction : it does not happens all the time, but more like 95% of the time.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to be stuck with Python 2? Otherwise, you should try to install Python 3.

Comment: Is this reproducible with just the code snippet above? Have you tried to reinstall `matplotlib` on your Win  partition?

Comment: I've a lot of python2.7 scripts, so python 3.x is not really a cool option. it is reproductible yes, happens every time. I've updated matplotlib, no luck

Comment: Does this happen outside of IPython/Jupyter as well? I.e. when you use a script with those two lines and run `python script.py` in a console?

Comment: Same issue in a python console. Also it appears to "only" happens 9 out of 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the BIOS and it seems to work now. As i9-7940X is very recent (Q3'17), my old BIOS version was supposed to work with it but was released before the CPU (06/17) so that might have been the issue.

I'll post again if blue screens come back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on an Alienware Area 51 machine. Fixed it by disabling processor's "hyperthreading" on the BIOS configuration. Also, I had a similar crashing issue on another machine with Ubuntu when trying to use multithreading.

In conclusion Matplotlib and multithreading don't get along well.